# SSIS package failing deployment to one server. with error "deploy_project_internal": A required privilege is not held by the client

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package that deploys successfully to several servers but fails on one with this error:

> "deploy_project_internal":  System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: A required privilege is not held by the client

I've gone through all the articles I can find on this error and nothing has worked yet. I've created a very simple SSIS package with no functionality to test deployment and it still fails with the same error. I've tried adding the permissions directly onto the SSIS component service objects as per one article I've found.

I've tried running the SSIS service with the same AD account as the engine service, I've tried running it as NT SERVICE\MsDtsServer150, always with the same issue. I'm running 2019 (RTM-CU19) Enterprise Edition. The Visual Studio Integration Services Deployment Wizard can can connect to the server during deployment with windows authentication and can see the integration services catalog on the server and when deployed it succeeds in loading project, connecting to destination server, changing protection level but fails on deploying project. I've installed SSIS on 3 other servers as a test and the same project succeeds on all three.

Comment: If you find that you need to copy pasta an entire paragraph, or more, from the top text box to the bottom one, you are ignoring the advice of the question wizard. Repeating entired paragraphs isn't helpful or useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in SSIS OS service. It is a leftover from the SSIS 2005 - 2008R2 era. Starting from SSIS 2012 onwards it is using SSIS Catalog and SSISDB database. Here is an excerpt from the Microsoft official documentation:

[Integration Services Service (SSIS Service)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/integration-services-service-ssis-service?view=sql-server-ver16)

> This service is not required to create, save, and run Integration
> Services packages. SQL Server 2012 (11.x) supports the Integration
> Services service for backward compatibility with earlier releases of
> Integration Services.

Please try to add your Windows AD account as a member to the **ssis_admin** role in the SSISDB database. It should allow you to deploy SSIS projects to that SSIS run-time server.